# Wordpress Custom Post Type is rewriting URLS for all other post types, pages and posts

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I have set up the following CPT called 'Services' using the code below in my functions.php file within my theme.

```
// Register Services Post Type
function services_custom_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
         'name'                    => _x( 'Services', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
         'singular_name'           => _x( 'Service', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
         'menu_name'               => __( 'Services', 'text_domain' ),
         'name_admin_bar'          => __( 'Service', 'text_domain' ),
         'archives'                => __( 'Service Archives', 'text_domain' ),
         'attributes'              => __( 'Service Attributes', 'text_domain' ),
         'parent_item_colon'       => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
         'all_items'               => __( 'All Services', 'text_domain' ),
         'add_new_item'            => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
         'add_new'                 => __( 'Add Service', 'text_domain' ),
         'new_item'                => __( 'New Item', 'text_domain' ),
         'edit_item'               => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
         'update_item'             => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
         'view_item'               => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
         'view_items'              => __( 'View Items', 'text_domain' ),
         'search_items'            => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
         'not_found'               => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
         'not_found_in_trash'      => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
         'featured_image'          => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
         'set_featured_image'      => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
         'remove_featured_image'   => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
         'use_featured_image'      => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
         'insert_into_item'        => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
         'uploaded_to_this_item'   => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
         'items_list'              => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
         'items_list_navigation'   => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
         'filter_items_list'       => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
         'label'                   => __( 'Service', 'text_domain' ),
         'description'             => __( 'My Services', 'text_domain' ),
         'labels'                  => $labels,
         'supports'                => array( 'title', 'editor', 'page-attributes' ),
         'hierarchical'            => true,
         'public'                  => true,
         'show_ui'                 => true,
         'show_in_menu'            => true,
         'menu_position'           => 5,
         'show_in_admin_bar'       => true,
         'show_in_nav_menus'       => true,
         'can_export'              => true,
         'has_archive'             => true,
         'exclude_from_search'     => false,
         'publicly_queryable'      => true,
         'capability_type'         => 'page',
         'menu_icon'               => 'dashicons-palmtree',
         'rewrite'                 => array('slug' => '/'),
     );
     register_post_type( 'services', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'services_custom_post_type', 0 );
```

I want the URLs of these CPTs to not have the word 'services' in them. So for a Services Post called 'Fire Prevention' I want the URL to be *mydomain.com/fire-prevention* **NOT** *mydomain.com/services/fire-prevention*.

I am finding that with the line:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => '/'),
```

in my $args, that the URL is doing exactly as I want.

**The problem is, now all of my other Pages and Posts are 404ing.**

I find if I change the permalinks to 'plain' then they all still work fine. I cannot use this though, it has to be 'Post name' for the permalinks.

If I remove the 'rewrite' argument from the CPT, then all the other pages work fine.

How can I make it so that the

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => '/'),
```

only works for the intended CPT and does not affect my other pages and posts?

My .htaccess file is fine and AllowOverride is set to ALL within Apache conf.

Comment: Do this help? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203951/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type-post-urls

Comment: It does indeed! That fixed it. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

So [this answer on another question resolved it for me.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/204210)

I added the following to my functions.php and it worked:

```
function na_remove_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {

    if ( 'services' != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) {
         return $post_link;
    }

    $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );

    return $post_link;
 }
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'na_remove_slug', 10, 3 );

function na_parse_request( $query ) {

    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || 2 != count( $query->query ) || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'services', 'page' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'na_parse_request' );
```